# Multiple input for grep

Tags: grep, terminal

Is it possible to use more than one input on Unix grep? Here is what I'm trying to do:

`pip freeze` list all installed python packages, but unfortunately also list it's dependencies

`cat requirements/base.txt` list my project packages

I've been trying to use something like `pip freeze | grep $(cat requirements/base.txt)` but without sucess.

Does anybody knows how to filter pip freeze to actually list only the packages I'm interested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your command put, just put double quotes around the command substitution.  For example, consider this `base.txt` file:

```
$ cat base.txt
simplegeneric==0.8.1
six==1.10.0
sympy==1.1
```

Without quotes, the command generates a series of errors.  With quotes, it works just fine:

```
$ pip3 freeze | grep "$(cat base.txt)"
simplegeneric==0.8.1
six==1.10.0
sympy==1.1
```

Better yet, unless you are familiar with regular expression syntax, it is probably safer to use the `-F` option so that grep interprets each line in `base.txt` as a plain string.  It makes no difference here but it may help avoid surprises in the future:

```
$ pip3 freeze | grep -F "$(cat base.txt)"
simplegeneric==0.8.1
six==1.10.0
sympy==1.1
```

Still better (hat tip: [Nasir Riley](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/270732/nasir-riley)), use the `-f` option to read the strings from a file without needing to use `cat`:

```
$ pip3 freeze | grep -Ff base.txt
simplegeneric==0.8.1
six==1.10.0
sympy==1.1
```

Comment: Ah, I was missing the double quotes! Thank you very much!!

Comment: The above command using `grep -f` is better as it avoids the useless use of `cat`. the `-f` switch tells grep to read the strings from the file directly so there's no need to use `cat`.

Comment: @NasirRiley Very good.  Answer updated with `-f`.